# selectively print few of the key value pairs in single line

Tags: python, json

while printing a recursive dictionary to a json in python, I need some of the keys in a single line, while some other keys in newline, I am aware that setting indent in json.dump gives a formatted output, but is there a way to selectively print few of the key value pairs in single line, for better readability

Answer (score 0):

To remove the new line "\n" character, you can use one of this two method:

```
line = line.replace("\n", "")
print(line)
```

or

```
print(line, end="")
```

Comment: I m using json.dump(dict_d1, fp, indent=1), but I need indent at some places, and no indent at some places in the same dictionary, is it possible

Comment: Do you need to indent or to go to a new line?
How do you decide to indent or not?

Comment: I need to group the relevant data in a single line at some places, for better readability

Comment: you need to be more specific, maybe you can share your code and json, explaining better what you want to do